# How to split and align equations in subequation mode with fractions

Tags: align, fractions, subequations, split

How to split this system of equations?

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    u_0&=\frac{c_{1,1} (c_{1,0}^4 (I_{0,1}-2 (I_{-1,0}-I_{-1,1}+I_{0,0}))+c_{1,0}^2 (c_{0,0}^2 (2 I_{-1,1}+I_{0,1})-c_{1,1}^2 (I_{-1,1}+2 I_{0,1}))+2 c_{1,1}^4 (I_{-1,0}+I_{0,0})-c_{0,0}^2 c_{1,1}^2 (I_{-1,1}+2 I_{0,1}))}{2 (c_{1,0}^2-c_{1,1}^2) (3 c_{1,1} c_{0,0}^2-2 (c_{1,0}^2+c_{1,1}^2) c_{0,0}+3 c_{1,0}^2 c_{1,1})}\\
    u_1&= \frac{c_{1,0}^4 (c_{1,1} (2 I_{-1,0}+I_{-1,1}+2 I_{0,0}-I_{0,1})-2 c_{0,0} I_{-1,1})+c_{1,1} c_{1,0}^2 (c_{0,0}^2 (I_{-1,1}-I_{0,1})+2 c_{1,1} c_{0,0} I_{0,1}-2 c_{1,1}^2 (I_{-1,0}+I_{0,0}))}{(c_{1,0}^2-c_{1,1}^2) (3 c_{1,1} c_{0,0}^2-2 (c_{1,0}^2+c_{1,1}^2) c_{0,0}+3 c_{1,0}^2 c_{1,1})}\\
    u_2&= \frac{c_{1,1}^2 (c_{1,0}^2 (c_{1,1} (I_{-1,0}-I_{-1,1}+I_{0,0}+I_{0,1})-c_{0,0} I_{0,1})-c_{1,1} (c_{0,0}^2 (I_{-1,1}-I_{0,1})-c_{0,0} c_{1,1} I_{-1,1}+c_{1,1}^2 (I_{-1,0}+I_{0,0})))}{(c_{1,0}^2-c_{1,1}^2) (3 c_{1,1} c_{0,0}^2-2 (c_{1,0}^2+c_{1,1}^2) c_{0,0}+3 c_{1,0}^2 c_{1,1})}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

[image]
I see how to split on single equation environment like this

```
u_0=\frac{\begin{split}
&c_{1,1} (c_{1,0}^4 (-2 I_{-1,1}-2 I_{0,1}+I_{-1,0}+2 I_{0,0})+2 c_{0,0}^4 (I_{-1,1}+I_{0,1})\\
&-\left(c_{1,0}^2+c_{1,1}^2\right) c_{0,0}^2 (2 I_{-1,0}+I_{0,0})+c_{1,0}^2 c_{1,1}^2 (I_{-1,0}+2 I_{0,0}))
\end{split}}
{\begin{split}
&2 \left(c_{0,0}^2-c_{1,0}^2\right) \left(2 c_{1,1} c_{0,0}^2-3 \left(c_{1,0}^2+c_{1,1}^2\right) c_{0,0}+2 c_{1,0}^2 c_{1,1}\right)
\end{split}}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

but doesn't work on subequations environment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You  have the `\splitfrac` command from `mathtools, which gives the possibility to write the numerator or the denominator of a fraction on two lines, somewhat like `multline`.

Answer (score 1):

I have two main suggestions. First, do take advantage of the fact that the denominator terms are identical (up to a factor `2` in the first subequation) across the three subequations. Let's call this common denominator `V`. This allows you to write

```
V^{-1}(<long numerator term>)
```

instead of

```
\frac{<long numerator term>}{V}
```

Second, use `aligned` environments to split `<long numerator term>` across two or three lines, as needed.

A third, minor suggestion would be to switch from `(...)` to `[...]` for "outer" parentheses. This'll help considerably with readability.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'subequations' and 'aligned' environments
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\begin{aligned}[t] #1 \end{aligned}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Put $V=(c_{1,0}^2-c_{1,1}^2) (3 c_{1,1} c_{0,0}^2-2 (c_{1,0}^2+c_{1,1}^2) c_{0,0}+3 c_{1,0}^2 c_{1,1})$. Then
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    u_0&=\tfrac{1}{2}V^{-1} \mybox{%
     &\bigl\{c_{1,1} \bigl[ c_{1,0}^4 [I_{0,1}-2 (I_{-1,0}-I_{-1,1}+I_{0,0})]\\
     &\quad +c_{1,0}^2 [c_{0,0}^2 (2 I_{-1,1}+I_{0,1})-c_{1,1}^2 (I_{-1,1}+2 I_{0,1})] \\
     &\quad +2 c_{1,1}^4 (I_{-1,0}+I_{0,0})-c_{0,0}^2 c_{1,1}^2 (I_{-1,1}+2 I_{0,1})\bigr] \bigr\}} \\[2\jot]
u_1&= \hphantom{\tfrac{1}{2}} V^{-1}\mybox{%
     &\bigl\{c_{1,0}^4 [c_{1,1} (2 I_{-1,0}+I_{-1,1}+2 I_{0,0}-I_{0,1})-2 c_{0,0} I_{-1,1}]\\
     &\quad +c_{1,1} c_{1,0}^2 [c_{0,0}^2 (I_{-1,1}-I_{0,1})+2 c_{1,1} c_{0,0} I_{0,1}-2 c_{1,1}^2 (I_{-1,0}+I_{0,0})] \bigr\} }\\[2\jot]
u_2&= \hphantom{\tfrac{1}{2}}V^{-1}\mybox{%
     &\bigl\{ c_{1,1}^2 \bigl[ c_{1,0}^2 [c_{1,1} (I_{-1,0}-I_{-1,1}+I_{0,0}+I_{0,1})-c_{0,0} I_{0,1}]\\
     &\quad -c_{1,1} [c_{0,0}^2 (I_{-1,1}-I_{0,1})-c_{0,0} c_{1,1} I_{-1,1}+c_{1,1}^2 (I_{-1,0}+I_{0,0})]\bigr] \bigr\} }
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank u so much, but what about if the denominator terms are so different?, I have others equations with this case. Thanks again.

Comment: @AugustoMeneses - If you have lots of fraction expressions where there's little commonality among the denominators, a different approach would be needed. What a "different  approach" may consist of will depend on a lot of things -- none of which I know anything about yet.